# List Column visibility

Tags: column

I have a list where users can create a new item. There is a column named "status" that should not be visible to users when adding a new item.

That column should be visible when editing an item and the user is able to give input to that column.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the NewForm.aspx and attach a script editor web part with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input[title='Status']").closest("tr").hide();

});

</script>
```

If this doesn't work, check your field name in the form and change out `Status` with whatever that name is.

Comment: Also :
Make sure you Status column is not marked as required field.

•Add above script to your form either using
1.Content Editor Web Part or
2.Add above code to a .js file and add it to scripts/style library. Add its reference to your page

Comment: removed my answer.. added comments only